# How do I trigger a CSS animation right before an element is destroyed?

Tags: dom, angularjs, css-animations

I am trying to animate a drilldown menu, so that when the user clicks on one option, the sub-options expand in an animated way, and when the main option is clicked again, the sub-options will collapse with an animation too.  The drilldown menu itself works, but the animations are giving me trouble.

I currently have the "expand" animation working correctly. When sub-option elements are created, they are given the class "drill-expand", that links them to the following CSS:

```
.drill-expand {
animation:expand 1s;
-webkit-animation:expand 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */ 
}
```

and a corresponding @keyframes animation. When the main option is first clicked, the sub-options are created, and appear according to the drill-expand animation.

But the problem arises in collapsing the sub-options. When clicking the main option to collapse the sub-options, I cannot get the sub-options to follow an animation. Instead, the DOM elements are just destroyed (correct behavior for the drilldown menu, but not pretty - I want an animation).  Is there a way to trigger the 'collapse' animation, right before the DOM elements are destroyed?

I am working with AngularJS 1.1.4, if that can be useful.

Thanks!

Comment: delay the element destroy by the animation duration (1s in this case).

Comment: I don't think there is a version 1.4.4. Either you are working with the 1.0.x (stable) branch, in which case, you'll have to keep the element around with a different class set on it, or you are using 1.1.x (unstable), in which case you should use [ngAnimate](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/04/animation-in-angularjs.html) to do that for you.

Comment: @musically_ut - sorry, I meant I'm using Angular 1.1.4, and ng-animate is not available until 1.1.5 unfortunately. It seems as if the only way to do this is with a setTimeout at the appropriate time.